# How to create a method using the Playground/Workspace (and not through the System Browser)?

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I am learning Smalltalk using Pharo+Squeak. I try to use the Playground/Workspace as a console, and figure out how to do everything there. One thing I have not figured out yet is how to add a method to a class.

Let's say I create a `Cat` class

```
Object subclass: #Cat
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'User Defined'.
```

To add a method `makeSound` to `Cat`, I can find it in the System Browser

```
Cat browse.
```

and create a new `makeSound` method there

```
makeSound
    "Make Cat object make sound."
    Transcript show: 'Meow!'.
```

I can then instantiate `Cat` and send it a `makeSound` message

```
cat := Cat new.
cat makeSound.
```

and it `Meow!` will show on the `Transcript` stream as expected.

Now, I do not know how to do all of this using the "console". In the *Pharo by Example* book it is mentioned that the convention for referring to methods is using `ClassName>>methodName`, and there are code snippets that look like this (I am probably butchering it!)

```
Cat class>>makeSound
  Transcript show: 'Meow!'.
```

It does not work when I type it in the Playground/Workspace.

Comment: Note that they way you are doing it now - in the System Browser - is the normal way - you don't do everything in the console.

Comment: *I try to use the Playground/Workspace as a console, and figure out how to do everything there.* Why do you need to do "everything" there?

Comment: @lurker I really like the purity of Smalltalk and know that it will improve my OOP skills, and am using Smalltalk for that purpose. I am too used to the *source file* paradigm, and want to use version control (re: `git`).

Comment: If you want to take the "command line" approach, you could consider using GNU Smalltalk. But if you want the full Smalltalk experience, which includes the environment, then Pharo / Squeak are the way to go, but then you should learn to roll with that paradigm. It sounds like you are using Pharo but then wanting to just roll with the command line approach, which is a bit awkward.

Comment: One of the objectives of [Cuis](https://github.com/Cuis-Smalltalk/Cuis-Smalltalk-Dev) is working well with Git. You could check that out, it's a small but nice Squeak fork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax is mostly used to insert methods into documents. It is not something that can be executed directly in the System Browser or in the Playground. For example take your method:

```
Cat>>makeSound
    Transcript show: 'Meow!'.
```

This just tells the reader that the method `makeSound` is in the class `Cat`. It's not executable. And it should be `Cat>>makeSound` and not `Cat class>>makeSound`. The second indicates that the method is on the class side.

You can add a method to a class from the Workspace by compiling it:

```
Cat 
  compile: 'makeSound
    "Make Cat object make sound."
    Transcript show: ''Meow!''.'
  classified: 'actions'.
```

You can also directly access the compiled method object from a class using the message`>>`: `Cat>>#makeSound`. Once you have this method object you can also execute it on an object:

```
(Cat>>#makeSound) valueWithReceiver: Cat new arguments: #().
```

Comment: How does this work? I looked up the `Cat` hierarchy in the System Browser (`Cat`->`Object`->`ProtoObject`) and cannot find a `compile:classified:` message anywhere. (Googling Smalltalk and compile is not helping. :/)

Comment: The method `compile:classified:` is defined in the trait `ClassDescription`. It is a message that classes (not instances) understand, that's why it is not in the `Cat` hierarchy as in that hierarchy you will find the selectors that instances of `Cat` understand, not the ones that `Cat` (the class object) responds to.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the "File Out" functionality and check the generated code, you will notice a syntax using exclamation marks. This is not the most readable syntax and is not meant to be read or written by humans.

Pharo, like Squeak, follows the Smalltalk-80 philosophy of taking advantage of the GUI to provide multiple tools, like the Playground, the Debugger, the Inspector and the System Browser, each providing a very specialized functionality. That's because Smalltalk (and some derived languages, like Self) is not simply about code, but objects and messages, and those can have multiple representations, usually visual ones.

The beauty of the thing is that everything is defined using this metaphor, including the environment tools. So you could easily change them to suit your development style, or install and use another one, like Calypso.

Even if you want to develop a more traditional script-style program, I suggest you try developing it using the System Browser, and resorting to the Playground only for some quick experimentation. Pharo is getting better at deploying "headless" applications so it won't be a problem.

If you are worried about Git, check Iceberg. It serializes your code in a mostly readable way so your diffs look nice on Github for example.